# Regex to validate phone number which is in the US Format

Tags: regex

> Should match the following:-

- `(222)-333-4444`
- `(010)-123-3435`
- `(100)-454-6565`

But Should disallow:-

```
(000)-000-0000
```

The only problem is when the input is entered all zeros. Otherwise my regex:-

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

works fine__.

**Demo**
http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: what is the language you're using?

Comment: @HamZa There is no regex to support the correctly marked answer unfortunately, although there has been a great insight in building a comprehensive regex and various other solutions given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?![0()-]+$)\(?(\d{3})\)?[-. ]?(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO5fS3/1)

- `(?![0()-]+$)` is a negative lookahead that says fail the match if matches only `[0()-]` character till the end.